# Access IPv6 home server remotely (also from IPv4 networks)

Tags: remote-access, ipv6, windows-server-2012, home-server, ipv4

I have an ISP that uses IPv6 and I want to set up a home server running windows server 2012 essentials and access it remotely using the remote web access feature. is this feature capable of IPv6? and if so how do I access the server form an IPv4 network?

Comment: IPv4 and IPv6 are sometimes referred to as two separate Internets.  If using IPv4, you can't communicate directly to an IPv6 address through the IPv4 protocol.  And, vice versa.  However, a device that can communicate on both Internets may be able to help, by relaying your traffic.

For example, the system using the IPv4 Internet can comm using IPv6, by using an IPv6 tunnel broker (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IPv6_tunnel_brokers .)  Hurricane Electric's http://tunnelbroker.net works well.  It may take time to learn routing, but is reliable and ought to (eventually) work.

Answer (score 0):

So your question is in two parts

1. Does windows server 2012 remote web access support IPv6? 
    **Yes.**
2. Can I access an IPv6 network from an IPv4 network? 
    **No.**

What you're asking for would be similar to me asking if I could call someone on skype by their username using my home landline phone - it is two entirely separate protocols. It is possible to communicate on both protocols separately, provided that your ISP is capable of providing this.

As TOOGAM suggested as a comment to this question, there are services out there that provide a `IPv6 <-> IPv4` proxy which you may be able to use or purchase to connect to your home IPv6 address from an external IPv4 network.